# Populate jQuery Autocomplete source from hidden field

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

First, I generate a list of strings in the codebehind. I would like to save this list to a hidden field and then use the list as the "source" for the jquery autocomplete function. Should I be converting my list to Json?

I tried something like this but it was unsuccessful:

```
var addressJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addresses);


<input type="hidden" name="Addresses" id="Addresses" value="@addressJson"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer

My hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfExistingTagList" class="tag-list" data-tag="" />
```

My jquery script that fetches the values from the codebehind thanks to ajax. Careful that I am using here the ["when" & "done"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) methods in order to fill the hidden input before the autocomplete method gets called:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.when($.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "NewsEditor.aspx/GetAvailableTags",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                    // The .d is part of the result so reference it
                    //  to get to the actual JSON data of interest
                    $('#hfExistingTagList').data('tag',result.d);
                }
                else {
                    // No .d; so just use result
                    $('#hfExistingTagList').data('tag', result.d);
                }
            }
        })).done((function () {
            $dbTags = $('#hfExistingTagList').data('tag').replace(/'/g, '').split(','); //Build the array used as the source for the autocomplete
            $('#tbMetatags').tagEditor({
                autocomplete: {
                    delay: 0, //show suggestions immediately
                    position: { collision: 'flip' },
                    source:  $dbTags
                },
                //...
                //Some stuff within my tageditor plugin
                }
            });
        }))});
```

And finally the webmethod in c# :

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetAvailableTags()
    {
        // Put logic here to return list of tags (i.e. load from database)
        var tags = new[] { "ActionScript", "Scheme" };
        return String.Join(",", tags.Select(x => String.Format("'{0}'", x)));
    }
```

Hope this will help! Works perfectly for me!